# Downgrade to Bazel 0.4.2 for Tensorflow r1.0

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, downgrade

I need to checkout to Tensorflow r1.0 and as suggested the Bazel version should be 0.4.2

I have already installed Bazel and after upgrade bazel version is 0.7.0

Do you know the steps so I can downgrade to Bazel 0.4.2?

I have tried with apt-get install bazel=0.4.2 but this does not work,

and I have also tried to uninstall by executing the command rm -fr ~/.bazel ~/.bazelrc and deleting relevant data in ~/.cache/bazel/ folder, but this did not also work.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using linux. Download bazel 0.4.2 executable from [Here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.4.2/bazel-0.4.2-installer-linux-x86_64.sh). Remove old version and install